# Duplicate Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet where I add in data about different items. I can have anywhere from 1-10 items. Each item has a different set of values attached to it and a report must be created for each item with the specified values. I have all of the values in different sheets in an excel file. I created an extra sheet that has the report. The report has the values concatenated into it.

I am attempting to copy the template report for each item and change the values in the report to match correct item. I have a loop that creates the correct amount of specific reports, but I cannot figure out how to have the loop insert the correct values while copying the report. I am brand new at VBA and trying to learn. This is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub Creating_New_Sheet()

    Dim i As Integer



    For i = 1 To Range("I4")

    Sheets(5).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Well" & " " & i

        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Active
        Range("B8").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""RE:""&""         ""&'Cost Summary'!RC[-1]"
        Range("B11").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=""Attached for your review and approval is AFE""&"" ""&'Cost Summary'!R[-3]C[7]&"" ""&""to install plunger lift on the"" &"" ""& 'Cost Summary'!R[-3]C[-1]&"". ""& ""The AFE amount is reflected in the Expenditures section of the AFE."""
        Range("B13").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=""Objective: The purpose of this workover is to install plunger lift on the""&"" ""& 'Cost Summary'!R[-5]C[-1]&"" ""& ""to stabilize production decline. Artificial lift intervention is required because gas rates for the""&"" ""& 'Cost Summary'!R[-5]C[-1]&"" ""& ""are no longer sufficient to adequately lift reservoir fluid from the wellbore.  If no intervention acti" & _
            "ken fluid will buildup in the wellbore adversely affecting the wells production and decline characteristics."""
        Range("B15").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=""Attached you will find a detailed cost estimate for plunger lift system installations on the"" &"" ""& 'Cost Summary'!R[-7]C[-1]&""""&"". Cost estimates were made using price sheets for material and services.  All other costs were estimated based on past plunger installation costs."""
        Range("B17").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=""Well History:""&"" ""& 'Cost Summary'!R[-9]C[-1]&"" ""& ""was turned to sales on""&"" ""& TEXT('Production and Well History'!R[-12]C[1],""MM/DD/YY"")&"" ""& ""and has produced for"" &"" ""&'Production and Well History'!R[-12]C[2]&"" ""&""days. The current production rates are""&"" ""& 'Production and Well History'!R[-12]C[3]&"" ""&""MCFD,""&"" ""&'Production and " & _
            "tory'!R[-12]C[4]&"" ""&  ""BOPD,""&"" ""& 'Production and Well History'!R[-12]C[5]&"" ""&""BWPD at wellhead pressures of"" &"" ""&'Production and Well History'!R[-12]C[6]&"" ""&""psi for casing pressure and""&"" ""& 'Production and Well History'!R[-12]C[7]&"" ""&""psi for tubing."""
        Range("B18").Select


    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you putting this in a standard module code sheet or a worksheet's private code sheet?

Comment: 1. What is in `Range("I4")` and what worksheet is `Range("I4")` on? 2. Are the values supposed to change in different new worksheets? They are all the same. 3. Do you have to retain the formulas or could you just write adjusted text into each cell?